# WebTestClient does not work when using spring-webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring webflux via Spring boot 2.0.0.M3. Below is the dependencies of my project,

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
        'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config',
        'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-stream',
        'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth',
        'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration',
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb",
        'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda',
        'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9',
        'org.javamoney:moneta:1.0',
        'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1',
        'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',
        'io.projectreactor:reactor-test',
        'org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker:6.1.2',
        'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo'
}
```

The app is running well via `./gradlew bootRun` or running main app directly.

However I failed to start integration test due to below error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

I'm wondering why **WebTestClient** still tries to use embedded tomcat even though we are using webflux that uses reactive-netty by default.

Is it something misconfiguration or bug of spring boot test?

Below is code snippet of my test case,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class NoteHandlerTest {

@Autowired
private WebTestClient webClient;

@Test
public void testNoteNotFound() throws Exception {
    this.webClient.get().uri("/note/request/{id}", "nosuchid").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange().expectStatus().isNotFound();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error of launching tomcat was caused by test dependency `org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker:6.1.2`, which depends on `javax.serlvet-api:3.1` break the tomcat's startup.

Excluding below useless modules to make tomcat launching again,

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'qpid-broker-plugins-management-http'
    all*.exclude module: 'qpid-broker-plugins-websocket'
}
```